# How can I use tag set in Django(jinja)?

Tags: django, jinja2

I want use  below code in Django template but I get this error : `Invalid block tag on line 255: 'set'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`.

```
{% set  Ne_page = page_data.current_page +1 %}
{% set  Pr_page = page_data.current_page -1 %}
```

When I use `{% load  set    %}` for load `set` tag I get this error: `'set' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of: admin_list, admin_modify, admin_urls,...`

I use another function like `if` or `for` and ... and work fine but when use set I have error, How can I use `set` tag for increment a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use `{% set %}` to create variable to store data in **`Jinja`** but django uses it's own template [**engine**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/templates/) not **Jinja** but if you want to use Jinja then you can change default [**Template Engine**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-backend/) to create variable in django use **[`{% with %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with)**
for addition use [**`add`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#add)

```
{% with  Ne_page=page_data.current_page|add:"+1" %}
{% endwith %}
```

---

```
{% with  Pr_page=page_data.current_page|add:"-1" %}
{% endwith %}
```

**Note** : you've to use your variable in between **with** **endwith** block 
eg.

```
{% with alpha=1 %}
   {{alpha}} use it inside block
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: I get this error 'with' expected at least one variable assignment

Comment: Hello @Tomy check I've edited my answer I did not noticed you're trying to add some value.

Comment: I edit but get same error

Comment: Hello @Tomy try removing empty space between ` = ` check I've edited my answer according to it

Comment: How can reuse variable and change its value after the first `{% with.`?

Comment: Hello @parmer_110 To assign value to the same variable, create another `with` block and change its value, but the updated value can only be used in that current `with` block.

Comment: Hello @AnkitTiwari, How can I update/ change the with variable within that with block? I have many nested for and if blocks and creating new with blocks are amusing.